# Using MySQL to sort by multiple, including random

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY revenue DESC
```

This query works as expected, ordering by the amount of revenue.

However, is there any way to randomize the order when multiple products have the same revenue?

I know you can `ORDER BY` multiple columns like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY revenue DESC, id ASC
```

But is it possible to use `ORDER BY RAND()` so if multiple products have the same revenue, they aren't always listed in the same order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any way to randomize the order when multiple products have the same revenue?

Just use `RAND()` as a second sort column:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY revenue DESC, RAND()
```